# how can I reconfigure the gnu assembler?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I need to compile a simple c/c++ file with g++.
I discovered that the output of as --version is the following:

```
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.22 (mspgcc dev 20120911)
Copyright 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `msp430'.
```

I don't want to compile for msp430.
How can I configure the assembler for my x86 or 64 bit architecture (i.e. for my PC)?

PS: Indeed, when I try to compile a "hello world", I have the following output:

```
g++ -o test test.c
as: unrecognized option '--64'
```

Comment: I tried also the options -m32 and -m64 but it doesn't work.

Comment: *"How can I configure the assembler for my x86 or 64 bit"* That's done when building it from source; setting a different configuration would require recompiling it yourself. But better just install a (precompiled) version that's known to work, e.g. from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) (uninstall any other versions of MinGW/GCC you have, or at least remove from PATH to avoid conflicts).